# Grails 3.3.5 REST configure HTTP header based authentication and authorization

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-3.3, pre-authentication

I am struggling mightily trying to configure Grails 3.3.5 to use HTTP header authentication/authorization on a REST project. I've tried about everything and can't seem to get it to happen. Does anyone have any pointers to a project or sample app that has this working?

I've tried a number of things with Authorization Providers, Authorization Managers, a custom user details services etc. all bound in with spring, but nothing seems to work.

What I want to do is very simple, look at HTTP header, lookup the roles from that, let the user access the resource or not. But I can't seem to find the right combination of configuration to accomplish this simple task with grails and spring. Many thanks for any pointers.